# How to activate ActiveMQ persistence to resist restart?

Tags: java, php, persistence, activemq-classic, mqtt

I do get ActiveMQ supports data persistence (http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html), but i cannot understand how to make it work, the result is when i restart ActiveMQ all the messages disappear, while queues and topics remain.

I've read about to enable persistence on a database but i want to keep data on the filesystem since my system is facing database perfomance issues.

This is my activemq.xml

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
<bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
      lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
      init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
</bean>

<!--
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" >
                <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                     slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                     by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                     For more information, see:

                     http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                -->
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <!--
        The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
        JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
        the JVM. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
        Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
        mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>


      <!--
        The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
        use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
      -->
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>

<!--
    Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
    The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

    Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

Comment: is it related to the fact subscribers must subscribe as durable?

Comment: can you please specify the mechanism you use for sending messages to the queue/topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, what i was looking for is to set Quality of Service > 1 for the publisher client, since the default QoS is 0.

Answer (score 4):

In order to enable persistence on the broker you have to choose a persistence adapter. You have done this by specifying in activemq.xml that you want to use KahaDB.

```
<broker brokerName="broker" persistent="true" ...>
    <persistenceAdapter>
         <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
</broker>
```

Ok, now the broker knows that you want to persist the incoming messages, but the client can still override this setting. In order to do that, you need to specify when sending a message that you want it to be persisted. Check what mechanism you are using for sending messages and make sure that they are set to be persisted.

For e.g. if you use Spring's `JmsTemplate` for sending messages you would have to call  [setDeliveryPersistent(...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#setDeliveryPersistent(boolean)). This is only an example, please note that the default for this method is *"true" aka delivery mode "PERSISTENT".*

Answer (score 2):

You need to send messages persistent as well. This is a client side thing to decide. In Java/JMS you would set the DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT while sending messages. In other client frameworks, like MQTT, there are other ways to specify it such as QoS = 1 or 2.